# Index and root pages are not working, 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx

The URL `example.org/index.php` (and any `example.org/etc.php`) **fail**, but `example.org/foo` working fine, for any `foo` folder.

```
server {
        server_name example.org example.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org.access_log;
        root /var/www/example.org/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =403;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

---

- nginx version: `1.17.10` (Ubuntu)
- ? `/var/log/nginx/error.log`  (no specific for the *server*?)

---

`sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` show nothing, only errors of other site,

```
...
2020/06/19 12:58:02 [error] 871296#871296: *23 "/var/www/example2.org/index2.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 181.177.112.xx, server: example2.org, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "example2.org"
```

---

MAIN CLUES TO THE SOLUTION (see my answer)

The file   `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` not exists, so the fail is at `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`.

`ls -l /run/php/*.sock`  shows

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root     30 May 17 05:18 /run/php/php-fpm.sock -> /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data  0 May 29 06:40 /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
```

Ideal is a generic socket, that is `php-fpm.sock`, but it is not seems the same (not redirect to `php7.4-fpm.sock`?).

Comment: Every `server {}` block should have a [`listen`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html). For example: `listen       80;` or `listen 443`

Comment: Hi @0stone0, not make sense, as I say in the question, it is working for `/foo` folder: a `listen` bug affect both, folder and root URLs. The `listen 80` is on the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` original NGINX script, that seems working  fine

Comment: May you post some log from error.log and /var/log/nginx/example.org.access_log ?

Comment: Hi @DilsonRainov, the file `access_log` is there, with no relevant information into, but **where the error.log?** Is the generic `/var/log/nginx/error.log`  or there are one specific for domain?

Comment: Ok. Can you ls the file /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock ? Looks like the php-fpm is not started.

Comment: Hi @DilsonRainov, you can post a little better answer, I edited the question, see "MAIN CLUES", and see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ideal is a generic socket, but at now using the `php7.4-fpm.sock`:

```
server {
        server_name example.org example.com;
        ...
        location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

This solution is not perfect (big problem when PHP changes version) but is working fine.

Comment: You can switch to php-fpm port, but this causes a slight slowdown. There is a little explanation here: https://www.tecmint.com/connect-nginx-to-php-fpm/

Comment: Hi @DilsonRainov, thanks the link (!).... Hum... It only say that my explicit version `unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock` is correct, and the alternative `unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock` is only for *CentOS*... Can you show what line I most include? Now my answer **is a Wiki**, you can edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a generic solution so you don't have to worry about the PHP version you could try:

```
server {
        server_name example.org example.com;
        ...
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

And check that in the file `/etc/php/7.*/fpm/php.ini` you have written the following line:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (adapt to your needs):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/example.org; //If Laravel /var/www/example.org/public
         
    index index.html index.htm index.php etc.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    
    client_max_body_size 1000m;
}
```

Notes:

1. The `server_name` ([doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)) variable holds the value `example.org`. This value must exists in the `hosts` file. Something like this `127.0.0.1 example.org`.
2. In the `root` variable the NginX is expecting the path where it will find the entry point of your system `/var/www/example.org/`. Here `example.org` is the file name for your project. If your entry point file is `index.php` or `etc.php` you must confirm that these files exists inside your root. Something like this:  `/var/www/example.org/index.php` or `/var/www/example.org/etc.php`. If you make your entry point inside another folder it will not work. Example if you setup the variable `root` to  `/var/www/example.org/public` (like Laravel) you should have your entry point file inside `public` folder, not inside `example.org` folder
3. The `index` variable is a list of possible entry point files in your `root` that NginX is expecting to find. In your case you should have something like  this: `index index.html index.htm index.php etc.php`.
4. The location for the php. If you are setting your NginX `variable` to `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` you must confirm that the file `php7.0-fpm.sock` already exists inside `/var/run/php/`
5. I put `client_max_body_size`, `fastcgi_buffer_size`, `fastcgi_buffers` if you want to perform an upload process to your server. If not, these variables are not necessaries.

And finally the error:

1. example2.org/index2.php" is not found. It seems that NginX is expecting to find `index2.php` entry point file inside the root folder `example2.org/`. Make sure that you have this file there.
2. I did not understand if you have php 7.0 or 7.4. In any case, You must pass the location of yours `php7.x-fpm` files. Just go there in the folder and confirm that they already exists.
3. And finally another possible error that you may face is permissions. Make sure that `www-data` (the NginX user) has appropriate permissions WRX to your files.
4. [Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) you will find how NginX process a request.
5. And [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) a compreensive list of variables used by NginX.